# How to handle JSON in POST body HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, json, servlets

I have a REST Java app based on servlets and I would like to manage requests like that:

```
curl -X POST -d "[{"label": "001", "value": 12345}, {"label": "002", "value": 54321}]" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' xxx.com/my/endpoint
```

Basically I'm sending a JSON array and the question is how can I properly parse it?
All I got at this moment was printing it using something like that:

```
String body = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

But I want to be able to handle every pair of label and value from the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution org.json and org.apache.commons.io

The simplest solution is probably doing the following

1. Convert input stream to string
2. Populate JSONArray with string using constructor
3. Loop through the array
4. For each interation grab the JSONObject from that iteration of the array
5. Grab the value of the member from the current object

You could also map the String to a set of classes that match the JSON Schema using JSON.  This is more complicated but it may be an alternate solution.  The biggest issue with that may be how to map an top level anonymous array to a class

```
String string = IOUtils.toString( request.getInputStream() );
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray( string );
JSONObject object;

for ( int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++ ) {
    object = jsonArr.getJSONObject( i );
    System.out.println( object.getString("label") );
    System.out.println( object.getInt("value") );
}
```

You will need to add the `org.json` and `org.apache.commons.io` dependency to your build path.  The following is a sample of how to add it to your project via Maven

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20210307</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

## Post Script

You stated this solution is stripping the leading zeros off the value of the label property. I believe this has to do with your request, not the code sample.  Try to either escape the nested double quotes or use single quotes

```
curl -X POST -d '[{"label": "001", "value": 12345}, {"label": "002", "value": 54321}]' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' xxx.com/my/endpoint
```

I believe the nested double quotes are causing the JSON to treat the value of the label property as numeric

Comment: Looks good, thank you. However can I limit the dependency and convert input stream to string using my method? I believe ioutils is used only for this purpose.

Comment: @RobertKwiatkowski you can convert it to a byte array then loop through the array and use string builder to build the string.  If size of the jar is a concern that is an option.  commons-io is pretty light though and I'm pretty sure thats the exact algorithm that the IOUtils.toString uses

Comment: @RobertKwiatkowski here is a tutorial that goes over some of that https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-string.  I would personally use commons-io unless you have a reason not to ( size of jar probably being the only one )

Comment: Actually, what does your body string contain?  Does it actually contain the entire request body?  if so just pass body to JSONArray constructor

Comment: My request body contains only json array

Comment: the provided solution truncates the "00" from start of label. Instead of expected "001" I receive "1". How can I fix it?

Comment: @RobertKwiatkowski check my Post Script in the answer